# При использовании метода json в fetch, массив в объекте данных становится пустым

Tags: javascript, json, async-await, fetch, response

Делаю запрос - в ответ должен прийти объект с данными.
Объект приходит и все данные есть, но проблема в том, что когда я вызываю метод json() то массив который находится в объекте становится пустым

```
const response = await fetch('URL'), {
  method: 'get',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
  }
});

// 1 вариант
console.dir(await response.json()) // {..., ..., [{...}], ...} все есть и все выводит правильно

// 2 вариант
const data = await response.json();
console.dir(data); // {..., ..., [], ...} массив стал пустым
```

Что я делаю не так во втором варианте?

З.Ы. это все находится в async function

Comment: А можно попытаться какой-нибудь воспроизводимый пример? Или хотя бы пример возвращаемых запросом данных. Пока все выглядит очень загадочно.
И да, это во всех браузерах так или в каком-то конкретном?

Comment: Немного смущает сам fetch запрос, а точнее как параметры передаются. Но это, видимо, просто ошибка при форматировании.

Comment: В консоль данные и выводятся как раз. 
Пример 1 варианта вывода в консоль:
{
  prop1: true,
  prop2: [
    {id: 123}
  ]
}

Пример 2 варианта вывода в консоль:
{
  prop1: true,
  prop2: []
}